# card-body in different levels of <div> in Bootstrap5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I am following a web application tutorial on Youtube and come into a question. As you can see from the code

```
<div class="card card-body">
 ...
</div>
```

The output is like
[image: card and card-body in same]

If I put `card` and `card-body` in different , the output would be strange.

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      ...
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: card and card-body in different]

Since I am new to Bootstrap5, this case makes me very confused. Of course the first one is the one I want but I still want to know the reason behind it.
Could someone please explain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a css rules that overwite the bootstrap with `!important`.

card(parent) and card-body(child) is the correct way according to [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/#about) so you should do it like that.

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      ...
     </div>
</div>
```